# How to switch to HDMI audio when HDMI is plugged in?

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, sh

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Right now, I am trying to make it so that my computer switches the audio output from my headphones to my projector when it is plugged in, and vice versa. Is there a way I can do this automatically?

Comment: Switching is automatic if the HDMI device is attached when you boot Ubuntu. Are you plugging the HDMI device in _after_ you boot?

Comment: Yes, I have it plugged in, but it is attached to a projector that isn't always on when Ubuntu boots

Comment: No, AFAIK, no automagicking, if the HDMI device is powered down. Of course, not that I have typed these words, someone will show me the way...